# Does apple offer a website to learn everything about ios (like android)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm android developer and looking ahead to ios development. I learn android from scratch to everything at [android officially developer site](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html). Does ios also offered this kind of website for us easy to learn? And swift or OBJ-C better for code ios application??

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action

Comment: I prefer Swift, more modern and safe in my opinion.

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise there both can do the same functionality??

Comment: Yes both languages are treated equally, there is no limitation. The common ground are the frameworks which are shared.

Answer (score 0):

"Everything about iOS" is a bit large, but Apple references a lot of ressources about Swift on this specific page : https://developer.apple.com/swift/. Have a look to ["The Swift Programming Language"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/), which is the reference book about Swift.

Apple also provides a book to learn Objective-C : ["Programming with Objective-C"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html), but a lot of other (better ?) ressources are available on the web or in books.

Here is also a basic tutorial from Apple to start programming apps for iOS : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343

On your last question, there are still a lot of debates in the iOS/Mac developers community. Swift is modern, secure and easy to learn, but not really finished. Objective-C is robust and helps you for a better understanding of the system. Both langages uses the same API and can do the same functionalities.